# How to slice 3d vec in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Python I would do `v[1:, 1:, 1:]`
How can I do the same in Rust?

I did not get the same result as in Python with `let v_ = &v[1..][1..][1..];`

In Rust v has type `std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<i32>>>`

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: can you please add the details such as what difference you observed? What did you expect in what way do you feel like the result is wrong?

Comment: You probably want to use the [`ndarray`](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray) crate.  There is a section in its documentation that may be of particular use: [`ndarray` for NumPy users](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/doc/ndarray_for_numpy_users/index.html), where under [Indexing and slicing](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/doc/ndarray_for_numpy_users/index.html#indexing-and-slicing) the example of `a.slice(s![1, .., ..])` is given as an alternative to `a[1, :, :]` in NumPy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that's possible in Rust, at least not in such a concise way.

Consider this "2d" variant (same principle, but simpler):

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![
        vec![10, 11, 12, 13],
        vec![20, 21, 22, 23],
        vec![30, 31, 32, 33],
    ];
    let v_ = &v[1..];
    println!("{v_:?}");
}
```

That outputs:

```
[[20, 21, 22, 23], [30, 31, 32, 33]]
```

Now, if you add another `[1..]` to `&v[1..]`, you will get:

```
[[30, 31, 32, 33]]
```

Why? Because the seconds `[1..]` is executed *after* the previous one, and as a result `[1..][1..]` works pretty much like `[2..]`.

It's hard to suggest a solution w/o knowing what your real case is. If you are looking for a simple way to just go over that sub-set of data, you might be just fine with a plain old nested loop, like this:

```
for x in &v[1..] {
    for y in &x[1..] {
        println!("The row is {x:?}, the value is {y}");
    }    
}
```